# How to get the delivery status of the notification send to Device using Firebase Cloud functions?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I'm building a Android Chat Application with the help of firebase , here I want to implement delivery feature for messages 
I can send notification using cloud functions but how to know if the message is successfully sent or not (Device may be offline).
Here I need to update my database [I need to update my state as 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1ZQY.jpg)if notification is successfully sent to device.
Please help !

Answer (score 0):

I got it , I've used data type payload to achieve my requirement !

As soon as I got the notification I've changed my message state to 2 in onMessageReceived .